# How to toggle two texts inside a button on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Looking for a proper way on toggling off two different text inside a button when firing an ajax call. One text should be displayed at once.

I am having an issue and how to specifically target the spans inside the button. I cant use the context of 'this' because it always referes to the single span.

I was thinking that after the ajax is done, add a class to one of the spans to hide it?

HTML

```
<button type="button" class="main-button" data-url={unfollowUrl}>
  <span class="text1">Text 1</span>
  <span class="text2">Text 2</span>
</button>
```

CSS

```
button {
  border: none;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

button .hide-text {
  display: none;
}
```

JS

```
$('button').click(function{
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: 'POST'
  }).done(function() {
    //toggling goes here

})
}
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5rk99y6y/

Comment: Is expected result that `<span class="text1">Text 1</span>` be toggled for `<span class="text2">Text 2</span>` on each click of `button` element ? `.hide-text` not appear at `html` ?

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="main-button" data-url={unfollowUrl}>
  <span class="text1">Text 1</span>
  <span class="text2 hide-text">Text 2</span>
</button>
```

JS:

```
$('button').click( function() {

    $curr = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://fiddle.jshell.net/',
        method: 'POST'
    }).done(function() {
        $curr.children('span').toggleClass('hide-text');
    });

});
```

CSS:

```
.hide-text {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Instead of linking to an external fiddle, why don't you just make your answer a Stack Snippet? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0

Comment: @Barmar thanks for your input, I've ignored that (actually very useful) feature long enough...

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio $curr is not in the scope of the done method.

Comment: @RichardBustos, it is in the scope; if you declare `var x = "checkme";` before the ajax call, and then you `alert(x);` inside the "done" function, it alerts correctly "checkme" **http://jsfiddle.net/eLom383c/3/**

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio hmm for some reason the example answer is not working?

Comment: @RichardBustos code taken from the answer: http://jsfiddle.net/eLom383c/4/ you click the button "text1", it changes to "text2" after a fraction of a second (time to perform the ajax request).

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Have a look here:  https://jsfiddle.net/5rk99y6y/1/</strike>

UPDATED: https://jsfiddle.net/5rk99y6y/26/

Just change the text of the span inside the button to what you want it to be, then update it as needed:

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="main-button" data-url={unfollowUrl}>
  <span>Text 1</span>
</button>
```

JS:

```
$('button').click(function(){
  var btn = $(this);
  var url = "/";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: 'POST'
      }).done(function() {
        var span = btn.find('span'),
            txt = span.text() ;
        if (txt == "Text 1") {
            span.text("Text 2");
        } else {
            span.text("Text 1");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: wont you be missing that initial click while you're setting txt = btn.text(); within that click function @swatkins ?

Comment: Try `btn.text().trim()` to remove the surrounding whitespace. https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/5rk99y6y/22/

Comment: I need to have it in spans for localization. It is done on the client